# Migrate Data from MongoDB to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We have database in mongo for a long time and now we have decided to move to Postgres. Since these two are totally different we have started with table design and API migration first. Now it comes to the data part.

In mongo, we have the following schemas and we wanted to migrate the same data to Postgres. I have gone through a couple of articles that say you can export data from mongo in CSV and import in Postgres using COPY command or using pgAdmin.

Mongos used uuid which is basically a string but in postgres we have id as an integer. we have used crossed ref foreign key in mongo as well how we can migrate those without lossing the connection between tabeles ?

can anyone suggest any good method ?

Comment: You could try one of the [mongo foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#NoSQL_Database_Wrappers). But why the complicated mapping between UUIDs and Integers? Why not just use the same UUIDs in Postgres as well (Postgres doesn't store them as strings)

Comment: yeah I mean I don't mind using the same data but when I export a single schema from mongo as CSV and try to insert it into Postgres it fails.

Comment: I will be more than happy if I get the same data in postgres. @a_horse_with_no_name